# prevent application from generate self-signed certificate on startup

Tags: docker, apache, apache2, icinga, icingaweb

Dears,

I have applications that run in a docker which are from https://github.com/REANNZ/etcbd-public.
the certificate of Icinga tool has expired and when I tried to install a new SSL from a Certificate Authority the system regenerates another self-signed SSL with the same name as server.crt and in the same directory which creates conflict and stopped the container. whenever I delete it and add the new SSL then reload apache2 it comes back again.

I would like to know where this certificate comes from and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, it was because the certificate that I am trying to install had an issue, that is why the system generates another OpenSSL cert to operate. then I generate another SSL, and it works.